# SQLite database on phonegap resultset length increase every time

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am developing an application using phonegap and i am using database as sqlite.
I have created a table using following commands:

```
   var dbb;
   var shortName = 'Vaccine1';
   var version = '2.0';
   var displayName = 'vaccine';
   var maxSize = 100000;
dbb = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
```

and inserted values using this function..

```
function AddDBvalues()
{

 dbb.transaction(function(tx){
//tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vaccin',nullHandler,nullHandler); 
tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vaccin(Vday INTEGER NOT NULL,VName TEXT NOT NULL, CCountryid INTEGER NOT NULL , Sex TEXT NOT NULL)', [],nullHandler,errorHandler);},errorHandler,successCallBack);
dbb.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Vaccin(Vday,VName,CCountryid,Sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["0","BCG","91","both"], nullHandler,errorHandler);});
dbb.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Vaccin(Vday,VName,CCountryid,Sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["0","OPV dose 1 of 5","91","both"], nullHandler,errorHandler);});
dbb.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Vaccin(Vday,VName,CCountryid,Sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["1","Hepatites B dose 1 of 2","91","both"], nullHandler,errorHandler);});
dbb.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Vaccin(Vday,VName,CCountryid,Sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["42","DPT dose 1 of 3","91","both"], nullHandler,errorHandler);});
dbb.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Vaccin(Vday,VName,CCountryid,Sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["42","OPV dose 2 of 5","91","both"], nullHandler,errorHandler);});
dbb.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Vaccin(Vday,VName,CCountryid,Sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["70","DPT dose 2 of 3","91","both"], nullHandler,errorHandler);});
}
```

and used this function to get valuse from database..

```
function ShowValue()
{
 var cnn = sessionStorage.getItem('cid');//getting from session 
  var cn=parseInt(cnn);
  alert (cn); //always show correct value
dbb.transaction(
 function (transaction) {
transaction.executeSql("SELECT * from Vaccin WHERE CCountryid='"+cn+"';",[],     dataHandler, errorHandler);});
function dataHandler(transaction, results){
      alert("first method" + results.rows.length);
    for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
      ...... }
}}
```

i am getting an unexpected error is that the length of resultset increase every time
means if run app first time it show correct value and when i run it again it just show the length of resultset = results.rows.length+results.rows.length means double and so on....every time.

please help me if anybody know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is AddDBValues getting called on every run of the app? IF NOT EXISTS has no effect on the insert statements.

Comment: yes AddDBValues getting called every time. but table should not be created every time if i am using " IF NOT EXISTS" . am i right??

Answer (score 1):

Is the database persistent between runs? If so then the data is doubling because not you're dropping the table. In you `AddDBvalues()` function the `DROP ...` command is commented out.

```
//tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vaccin',nullHandler,nullHandler);
```

Unrelated but you also have a possible SQL injection vulnerability. The variable `cn` should be passed in as a bind variable and not simply added to the SQL as a string.

```
transaction.executeSql("SELECT * from Vaccin WHERE CCountryid='"+cn+"';",[],     dataHandler, errorHandler);});
```